# Inject data into com port

Tags: port, virtualization

I have a psyhical device that sends data to an application.

My question is :

Is there a way I can inject data to that application using the same COM port as the device uses ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but none that I know of are particularly easy.

The technical answer is going to vary between systems, but the way I would do this would be to create a filter driver that sits between your application and true serial driver. Then you can snoop the packets coming across and inject your data as necessary. If your OS doesn't support filter drivers then replacing the serial driver with a modified version would be the way to go.

If you can revise your question to provide more details, I can do the same with my answer.